# Query a table/database in Athena from a Notebook instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker, pyathena

I have developed different Athena Workgroups for different teams so that I can separate their queries and their query results. The users would like to query the tables available to them from their notebook instances (JupyterLab). I am having difficulty finding code which successfully covers the requirement of querying a table from the user's specific workgroup. I have only found code that will query the table from the primary workgroup.

The code I have currently used is added below.

```py
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd
conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='<ATHENA QUERY RESULTS LOCATION>',
region_name='<YOUR REGION, for example, us-west-2>')


df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM <DATABASE-NAME>.<YOUR TABLE NAME> limit 8;", conn)
df
```

This code does not work as the users only have access to perform queries from their specific workgroups hence get errors when this code is run. It also does not cover the requirement of separating the user's queries in user specific workgroups.

Any suggestions on how I can add alter the code so that I can run the queries within a specific workgroup from the notebook instance?

Comment: I am not familiar with `pyathena` but after a quick look I found parameter `work_group` which can be passed to `connect`. Have you tried to use it?

Comment: @IlyaKisil No I haven't tried it.. I couldn't find anything online documentation wise. Would you be able to link me to where you found this? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation of `pyathena` is not super extensive, but after looking into source code we can see that `connect` simply creates instance of `Connection` class.

```py
def connect(*args, **kwargs):
    from pyathena.connection import Connection
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, after looking into signature of `Connection.__init__` on [GitHub](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/blob/master/pyathena/connection.py) we can see parameter `work_group=None` which name in the same way as one of the parameters for `start_query_execution` from the [official](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution) AWS Python API `boto3`. Here is what their documentation say about it:

> WorkGroup (string) -- The name of the workgroup in which the query is being started.

After following through usages and imports in `Connection` we endup with [BaseCursor](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/blob/master/pyathena/common.py) class that under the hood makes a call to `start_query_execution` while unpacking a dictionary with parameters assembled by `BaseCursor._build_start_query_execution_request` method. That is excatly where we can see familar syntax for submitting queries to AWS Athena, in particular the following part:

```py
if self._work_group or work_group:
    request.update({
        'WorkGroup': work_group if work_group else self._work_group
    })
```

So this should do a trick for your case:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pyathena import connect


conn = connect(
    s3_staging_dir='<ATHENA QUERY RESULTS LOCATION>',
    region_name='<YOUR REGION, for example, us-west-2>',
    work_group='<USER SPECIFIC WORKGROUP>'
)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM <DATABASE-NAME>.<YOUR TABLE NAME> limit 8;", conn)
```

Comment: This works for me & i get the df but i also get the following; UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this it worked for me.

```
!pip install pyathena
```

Ref [link](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/#pandas)

```
from pyathena import connect
from pyathena.pandas.util import as_pandas
import boto3


query = """
    Select * from "s3-prod-db"."CustomerTransaction" ct where  date(partitiondate) >= date('2022-09-30') limit 10
"""
query

cursor = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://s3-temp-prod2/',
                 region_name=boto3.session.Session().region_name, work_group='data-scientist').cursor()
df = cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.state)
print(cursor.state_change_reason)
print(cursor.completion_date_time)
print(cursor.submission_date_time)
print(cursor.data_scanned_in_bytes)
print(cursor.output_location)
df = as_pandas(cursor)
print(df)
```

If we dont pass `work_group` parameter will use "primary" as the default work_group.

If we pass `s3_staging_dir='s3://s3-temp-prod2/'` s3 bucket which does not exist, it will create this bucket.

But if the user role that you are running the script does not have to create bucket privilege it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The method by @Ilya Kisil worked for me, but as mentioned above i got a userWarning. My solution is as follows:

```
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd

# Specify your Athena query
query = "SELECT * FROM db-name.your_table_name limit 10;"

# Create a connection to Athena
conn = connect(s3_staging_dir='s3://your-bucket-name/query-results/',
               region_name='your-region-name', 
               work_group='your-workgroup')

# Create a cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute the query
cursor.execute(query)

# Get column names from cursor description
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

# Fetch the results as a DataFrame
results = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=column_names)

# Display the results with column headings
print(df)
```